# How to display decimals python 3.6.0

Tags: python

I don't understand how to get the result to show decimals. I'm sure this is super easy and I'll kick myself but I've looked all over and can't figure this out.(yes I'm very new to python) Thanks in advance.

```
weight = input ("Enter Weight: ")

if int(weight) <= 2:
    rate = 1.10
elif int(weight) > 2 and int(weight) <= 10:
    rate = 2.20
else:
    rate = 3.70

charge = int(weight)*int(rate)

print (charge)
```

Comment: Instead of `int`, use `float` for type-casting

Comment: change `charge = int(weight)*int(rate)` to `charge = weight*rate`

Comment: If you're doing financial computations then maybe you should consider using `Decimal` which is fixed point numbers.

Comment: Float did the trick, I would have sworn I already tried that thanks a ton.